# Connecting a Gas Dryer to a Propane Tank

Tags: dryer

I have a gas dryer for sale, but do not have a gas line hook-up.
Can I use a small propane tank to test the dryer for potential buyers?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This is a duplicate of an existing question, and will be closed soon. You should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a duplicate but I did not see an accepted answer. 
I have hooked up both propane and natural gas dryers in the past. You can hook a dryer up to a propane or some call LP gas tank with a regulator. The one difference from the instructions in both dryers and stove/ ovens is there is a different size orifice on the output of the regulator to make it work correctly, right now I cannot remember off the top of my head I can’t remember  the sizes but in the past I have set up gas furnaces, barbecue’s, water heaters and stove tops and ovens and the only difference was a small brass orifice that you changed one size worked for natural gas the other worked for LP/ propane. I am sure a quick search will verify this.

Comment: The answers are, however, relevant making exactly the same points you make. The OP on that older post not accepting any one of the answers is minor...